# Best data structure design in Firestore between two?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have a doubt on how to structure my firestore data.

Daily, I have information like:

```
TodayDate, From, ToUser1, Subject, Attachment2, AttachmentTypeB
TodayDate, From, ToUser1, Subject, Attachment3, AttachmentTypeA
TodayDate, From, ToUser2, Subject, Attachment4, AttachmentTypeA
TodayDate, From, ToUser2, Subject, Attachment5, AttachmentTypeC
```

Subject and From are never the same.

I am hesitating between Two structures but I am opened to consider other structure design.

```
0/ Root / doc / sub col / sub col fields

1/ users / userid / date / from,subject,etc
OR
2/ reports / date / userid / from,subject,etc
```

I believe solution 2 will be more cost saving in the long run since for one query, I will have more records per date than records per user. For the update, it is similar.

What are your advice, please?

Kind regards,

Julie

Comment: Both options appear like large JSON trees and suggest you are considering using realtime-database and not firestore. Do I understand that TodayDate, From, etc are all properties on a typical record within your data?

Comment: Yes you understand right. I could use Firebase DB? Would it make more sense in term of cost ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your current data structure, I suggest you simply use cloud firestore instead of realtime-database, as that scales better and you get quite good performance for very low cost.

You could start a collection, with each of the records containing your listed attributes: `TodayDate, From, ToUser2, Subject, Attachment5, AttachmentTypeC`. And its easy to query using where:

```js
firestore().collection("myCollection").where("subject", "==", subject).get()
```

See this [comparison](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore).

UPDATE: Regarding your two options, I don't think it comes down to which option fetches/updates more/less records. It comes down to your app's requirements/actual usage. You might need to fetch the records for a specific user and not just for a specific date and vice versa. So, both structures don't really make any difference in terms of cost, unless you're sure you're sure you'll never need to fetch records per user.

Hence, I think the main focus should be on how intuitive and flexible your structure is and how easy it is to maintain over time. You should consider not using sub-collections in the first place, as it appears (from your daily record data) you could achieve what you need and get a more flexible structure with a simple collection containing documents with the necessary properties. I think sub-collections are generally needed when you are don't want to always fetch all properties of a record or when you want real-time listeners for specific properties and not the entire record. Sub-collections don't really increase/reduce the amount of records fetched, that depends on actual usage

Comment: Thanks I was already on the verge of picking firestore, it is just I am not sure how to design it. I am hesitating between 1/ users (as col) / userid (as doc) / date (as subcol) / from,subject,etc OR 2/ reports (col) / date (doc) / userid (subcol) / from,subject,etc

Comment: Thank for the answer !

Comment: Last thoughts, the records are organized via users or date, I don’t know how to get rid of the subcollection level. The records are basically like emails inbox recordings and I need to be able to distinguish the records by date and user.

Comment: Each document in your collection could have `date` and `userid` attributes. When fetching, use the `where()` clause to distinguish. Like `firestore().collection("myCollection").where("userid", "==", userid).get()`. You could also chain where clauses to create more complex queries. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries